# TIF Converted to PDF with PDFSharp and System.Drawing Loads in Chrome and Edge But Blank in Firefox/pdf.js/react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, pdf.js, pdfsharp

I have converted a TIF into a PDF with System.Drawing and PDFsharp-gdi (version 1.50.5147) in my .NET 6 API. I am sending the file as a base64-encoded string to my react frontend that uses [wojtekmaj/react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) as the PDF viewer. However, the TIF needed to be resized due to being larger than the max allowed size for PDFs (200in x 200in) in the API which I did with the following:

```cs
System.Drawing.Image MyImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(inStrm);
XImage img = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(MyImg);
var p = new PdfPage();

double maxRez = 14400.0;
if (MyImg.Width > maxRez || MyImg.Height > maxRez)
{
    double factor = 0.0;
    if(MyImg.Width > MyImg.Height)
    {
      factor = (double)(MyImg.Width) / maxRez;
    }
    else{
      factor = (double)(MyImage.Height) / maxRez;
    }

    p.Width = MyImg.Width / factor;
    p.Height = MyImg.Height / factor;
}

doc.Pages.Add(p);
XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[PageIndex]);
xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, p.Width, p.Height);
```

Normally sized images (not beyond 200inx200in are converted and displayed fine). Why would PDFs generated after being resized not load correctly? This issue also occurs if I download the file and load it as a PDF in Firefox, which uses PDF.js under the hood I believe.

In Firefox, the error is `An error occurred while rendering the page. PDF.js v2.4.152 (build 827eb64b) Message: Stack: putBinaryImageData@resource://pdf...`, which I have tried looking up but no solutions have been suggested.

Comment: Without the TIFF image we cannot replicate the issue. Are you using an official PDFsharp version? If so, which one? Why don't you create the XImage from stream? This could make a difference.

Comment: I suppose I get what you mean K J, but how would we constrain it and why would the PDF load in Chrome then? Does Chrome do additional conversions or rescaling that firefox doesn't?

Comment: @IlikedtheoldStackOverflow I have added the PDFsharp version (gdi with exact version number). I am actually adding support for multipage TIFF images and so was using `MyImg.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)` to get the number of pages and `MyImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, PageIndex)`, where `PageIndex` is a counter, in order to convert each TIFF page into a PDF page. Can I do the same with a with the `FromStream(inStream)`, where `instream` is a Memory stream? I believe I tried it a while ago but don't remember why I went with `FromGdiPlusImage` except to handle multipage TIFFs.

Comment: What I would do: I'd add pages in A4 format and scale images to suit the A4 size in the `DrawImage` call. Is there a reason why you cannot do that?
Have you tried setting "maxRez" to e.g. 1000, 100, or even 20? The image will look the same, only the scaling factor in the viewer changes.

Comment: Note that PDF pages do not have pixels. The dimensions of PDF pages are set in points and 72 points are one inch. You set the point size of the page to match the pixel size of the image. This can make sense, especially for images scanned with 72 DPI. But this does not always make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to resize the image being embedded first, then adding it to the PDF page after it has already been resized. I was previously trying to resize the PDF which would allow the PDF to be loaded but none of the images because their resolution was greater than what is supported in PDF files. Refer to this [article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ishbandhu2009/resize-an-image-in-C-Sharp/) for how to resize images.

If you are working with multi-page images, scale each one iteratively with `MyImg.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page)` and select active frame with `MyImg.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, PageNum)`.